# Recommended approach for namespace handling in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, resharper, intellisense

We have a set of javascript «modules» organized in «namespaces» — object hierarchy rooted in the global object (window).

In some cases we use an utility `createNs("namespace.name")` (it works exactly like YUI `YAHOO.namespace`), however we have **no IntelliSense** with it. ReSharper cannot resolve such too.

For now, the only way to make IntelliSense work is writing extremely bothering stuff like the following:

```
// module with no dependencies:
(function (window) {
    var ourCompany = window.ourCompany || (window.ourCompany = {});
    var components = ourCompany.components || (ourCompany.components = {});
    var emails = components.emails || (components.emails = {});
    emails.inbox = {
        checkNew: function () { }
    };
})(window);

// consumer:
(function (window) {
    window.ourCompany.components.emails.inbox.checkNew();
})(window);
```

Another option is using `jQuery.extend` method which is not always available:

```
// depends on jquery:
(function (window, $) {
    $.extend(true, window, {
        ourCompany: {
            components: {
                emails: {
                    inbox: {
                        checkNew: function () { }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
})(window, jQuery);
```

What's the common denominator solution?

- Write less,
- Have intellisense,
- Have ReSharper's refactorings,
- No 3rd party dependencies.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, here are your options:

1. You can write a R# plugin to resolve your utility method. I can tell you where to look if you are interested.
2. You can try to use Visual Studio Intellisense for JavaScript (ReSharper | Options -> Environment | Intellisense | General -> Limited ReSharper IntelliSense -> Turn on everything except JavaScript). This would affect only Intellisense, all other ReSharper features would continue to work.
3. In ReSharper 7.1 we provide Intellisense with all identifiers that were encountered in JS files. Maybe it would be sufficient for you.
4. If you are not using `/// <reference path="path-to/another-script.js" />` then you can create a separate JS file (that won't be really included anywhere) with code like

   ourCompany.components.emails = {};